# Trying to debug .NET 7 running in a Docker container remotely on Linux

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

Using VS (17.5.3) to debug a .NET 7 app running in a Docker container on a remote Linux server and get this in the output:

Any ideas? Is it the file to copy that's not found locally or is it the sftp-upload that fails, or am I missing the write permission on the target? my sftp-log is empty...

```
Failed to launch debug adapter 'coreclr'.
Unable to find debugger script at '/root/.vs-debugger'.


Initialization log:
Determining user folder on remote system...
Checking for existing installation of debugging tools...
Downloading debugger launcher...
Creating debugger installation folder: /root/.vs-debugger
Copying debugger launcher to /root/.vs-debugger/GetVsDbg.sh
Failed: Failed to upload file '/tmp/Microsoft-SSHPortSupplier-FileCopy-e7ea9cb4-21b0-4a5d-a3b3-a17de723133c'
to target 2041495049: No such file
Unable to find debugger script at '/root/.vs-debugger'.
Failed: Unable to find debugger script at '/root/.vs-debugger'.
The program '[1] dotnet' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).
```